# z-index: Kendo Popup vs loading overlay

Tags: html, css, kendo-ui

I am trying to display a loading overlay during an async AJAX call, but I can't seem to display it over Kendo Popup. The pop up always stays on top.

```
<!-- Animation while loading -->
<div class="loading-overlay" style="display: none;">
    <i class="fa fa-fw fa-5x fa-refresh fa-spin"></i>
</div>

.loading-overlay {
   position: fixed;
   top: -50px;
   bottom: 0;
   left: -50px;
   right: 0;
   cursor: wait;
   z-index: 10000000000000000000000000000000;
   background-color: rgba(0,0,0,0.2);
   color: #3174ad;
   text-align: center;
   padding-top: 30%;
}
```

How can I make the animation go on top?

Comment: can you post you full code for better understanding? @Uğur Dinç

Comment: I found the issue. It seems that if the AJAX call is not async, then it freezes the rest of the script code.